# Constructor call is a prvalue expression

Tags: c++, constructor, prvalue

In the C++ [standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) one can find examples of prvalue expressions:

> "prvalue
>
> The following expressions are prvalue expressions:
>
> a literal (except for string literal), such as 42, true or nullptr;
>
> **a function call or an overloaded operator expression of non-reference return type, such as str.substr(1, 2), str1 + str2, or it++;** 
>   ..."

Is this where an expression such as `T()` (a constructor call) would go?

Is there another name for such expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the particular case of a default constructor puzzles me a bit, this is considered a *cast expression*, which is a bit lower on the list:

> - a cast expression to non-reference type, such as `static_cast<double>(x)`, `std::string{}`, or `(int)42`;

Even though the idea of converting *nothing* is peculiar, the `T()` syntax is indeed covered as form #4 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).

Comment: Is it considered a cast because the initializer (the parameters of the constructor are called 'initializer', am I right?) is converted to type `T`?

Comment: I found another [page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) where this specific expression is mentioned: "3) initialization of a prvalue temporary by functional cast or with a parenthesized expression list". It seems strange (for me) to refer to a constructor call as a cast, but if that is how the standard refers to it so be it.

Comment: @user42768 that's the gist of it, yes.

Comment: Ok. So a `direct initialization` (as in the page that I linked in my previous comment) is still considered to be a cast. Thank you!

Comment: @user42768 only if it's creating a temporary, if memory serves.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that is what I meant. Does the standard explicitly mention this?

Comment: @user42768 it's about time I think of mentioning this: "cast" and "explicit conversion" are interchangeable. It's about constructing a temporary `T` from some (or no) original object(s).

Comment: I found in the [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) you provided at point 3: "new_type ( expressions )  (3)". This is what I was looking for. Thank you again!